# Using “tools” namespace to preview data on a WebView and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-viewpager, android-webview, design-time

In Android Studio, if you want to add some data in layout preview, you can simply use `tools` namespace.

[image: Sample]

It was quite simple for TextView, ImageView and so on.

What about a `WebView`? Is it possible to show an URL (local) in design time?

And what about `androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager`? Is it possible to add some tab just to show anything at design time?

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the same. Incredibly, 2 years later (2021) you can't set a "tools" preview for WebView, according to official docs:

[Tools attributes reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes#design-time_view_attributes)